# MASTER KEY NOT GENERATED RAILS 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credentials

I have scaffolded a rails application (v6.0.3.4), after one day I realised that the master key wasn’t there.
I know I can generate it, but it wouldn’t be the 'original', as I understand it.

Is it any possibility that the master key is there and I need a command to make it visible ?
Is there any other solution than scaffolding again?

Comment: `master.key` is not committed to Git by default. Did you clone the original code on a separate machine? Also, your rails version should be be 6.0.3.4 and not 6.9.3.4

Comment: Yes, indeed its 6.0.3.4. I haven’t cloned. I am the one that did the scaffold and push to my team members. Now, one of them requested it and there is where I figure it out that there was no key.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are looking for the file `config/master.key` right?

Comment: Exactly, because it should be there when you scaffold, as far as I know

Comment: I am not sure why it wasn't generated, but you should be fine with generating a new master.key file. I am assuming you do not have a credentials.yml.enc file yet, which is what the master.key is used to encrypt.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I wasn’t sure about the implications that the master key could bring me in the future. But it seems more straightforward that I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not use credentials in this project before:

1. If there is a credentials.yml file available - delete it.
2. To generate a new credentials.yml file + a master.key, you need to run in your console:

`rails credentials:edit`
or `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`

3. the credentials.yml file will be automatically added to git. the master.key will not be commited for security reasons. Save it in a separate place.

Comment: Such a helpful answer. 
Thanks!!

Comment: if it solved your issue, click the button to mark it as the answer

Comment: This does not work for me. I've made sure to `unset RAILS_MASTER_KEY` and delete any credential files

Comment: are you sure that you are using Rails 6?

Answer (score 0):

- Delete credentials.yml.enc & master.key
- **RUN** `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit`

When you commit, master.key file will not be committed to Git as it is included in .gitignore by default.

Comment: Welcome to SOF, please comment one-line answers - if you want to post it as an answer add more notes and references, thanks